# Android 8.1.0 slows down after last update 5th Jan

Tags: updates, 8.0-oreo

Do you know the reason of totaly slow down of Adnroid 8.1.0 (Nexus5X) after last update 5th Jan? It seems it was security update about CPU vulnerability. My phone become so slowly as never before.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems it was security update about CPU vulnerability.

That's putting it mildly. You may have heard in the news recently about the Meltdown and Spectre exploits, which demonstrate vulnerabilities in all Intel CPUs. Some variants of these attacks also work against Cortex-A [ARM CPUs from about 2005 onward](https://developer.arm.com/support/security-update): the CPUs in almost all Android phones. [Here's some discussion on the Infosec Stack Exchange site.](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/176803/102155)

All OS vendors - desktop, server, and mobile - are shipping updates that *mitigate* against the vulnerabilities, but because the problem is in the CPU itself, and relates to the performance optimizations that the CPU performs, the mitigation slows down the CPU significantly. Some people have reported 50% slowdowns on some types of program, though 20-30% is closer to what most people are seeing.

I'm afraid you'll just have to put up with the slowdown. It's the only way to avoid the security problem. Not patching the update would mean any app on your phone, scripts on any website you visit, and scripts from ads in apps or websites, can all read any memory of your phone - including your passwords, credit card numbers, and access tokens used by Android to control what apps can do. The attack is undetectable, so you wouldn't know it has happened to you.

All but the oldest Android phones and tablets will need this patch: it's not just for the Nexus 5X, and not even just for Nexus phones. If anyone else has a phone whose manufacturer has stopped updating, they need to install an up-to-date custom ROM, or get a new phone.